# appying a function to dataframe's index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to make a function that receives a number `X` and then divides two specific columns in the `X` row. Then I need to make a whole column (using my function and apply) that shows the quotient of the two columns. How can I apply a function to a DataFrame index and make it a column ?
Here's my function:

```
    def ratio(x):
       Length = df2.iloc[x]['Sepal.Length']
       Width = df2.iloc[x]['Sepal.Width']
       return Length/Width
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to make a `ratio` column based on two other columns, you can simply do this and it will create a new column without the need to iterate over all rows:

```
df2['ratio'] = df2['Sepal.Length'] / df2['Sepal.Width']
```

And if you still wish to use a function and `apply` it you can do it using [apply()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html). You'll also need to change your function according to `apply` as it takes the parameters as entire rows:

```
def ratio(row):
  Length = row['Sepal.Length']
  Width = row['Sepal.Width']
  return Length/Width

df2['ratio'] = df2.apply(ratio, axis = 1)
```

Comment: yeah thats exactly what I want to do,but I need to do it with the function...

Comment: an eror popped up after writing this line " invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'setosa' "
on the length line in the function,why is that?

Comment: I have made some changes to your function based on how `apply` works, it should work fine now.